How can one find the partial fraction decomposition of a function with an irreducible quadratic denominator?
The textbook I'm reading goes over how to evaluate integrals using partial fraction decomposition. They went over partial fraction decomposition by listing four examples that, more or less, every rational function with a negative degree should reduce to:

$$ \frac {1} {(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)} =  \frac {A} {x-1} + \frac {B} {x-2} + \frac{C}{x-3}\tag{1}$$ $$\frac {1} {(x-1)^3 (x-2)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{C}{(x-1)^3} + \frac{D}{x-2} \tag{2} $$ $$\frac{1}{x^2 (x^2 + 1)} = \frac{A}{x} + \frac{B}{x^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2 + 1} \tag{3}$$ $$ \frac{1} {(x-1)^2(x^2+1)^2} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{Cx+D}{x^2 + 1} + \frac{Ex+F}{(x^2 + 1)^2} \tag{4} $$

They then went over a few straightforward examples, and then offered three problems for the reader. One of these problems read the following:

Evaluate $$ \int \frac{x-3}{x^2 - 3x + 3}dx$$

I'm confused. The denominator does not factor, and this expression does not appear to simplify into one of the four above examples. I looked online for information on how to find this integral, and none of the solutions use partial fraction decomposition. I do not have access to the solutions for this textbook, so I'm really curious: how was this meant to be solved taking into account the fact that it was included as a problem following an explanation of partial fraction decomposition? In general, how can one find the partial fraction decomposition of an expression with an irreducable denominator like this one?

You can’t decompose that fraction. Partial fraction decomposition breaks a fraction down into fractions that have a denominator that is a factor of the original denominator. Since the original denominator is irreducible Partial Fraction Decomposition can’t be used here. Maybe $u$ sub, maybe another method.

Every polynomial factors (over the complex numbers).  In this case $x^2 - 3 x + 3 = (x - 3/2 - i \sqrt{3}/2) (x - 3/2 + i \sqrt{3}/2)$.  But if you don't want to use complex numbers, use a substitution to get a denominator $u^2 + 1$, which you should know how to deal with.

The reason it is included in this section of your textbook is that you have to know what to do $\textit{after}$ the partial fraction decomposition

@eti902 I don't understand what you mean.

Suppose this is part of a bigger question, and using partial fraction decomposition, you obtain this fraction (and others). Then what do you do? This problem is to help you answer this question.

The problem is in the same class of problems as
$$
\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,dx
$$
The integrand is a rational function with negative degree and a denominator that consists of a quadratic polynomial that does not factor, exactly like the integrand shown above. This means that this is how far you get with (real) partial fraction decomposition. From here on, the task to get the antiderivative $F(x)$ is not related to partial fraction decomposition, anymore. The same holds for finding the antiderivative of rational functions with higher powers of irreducible quadratic polynomials in the denominator.
Integrals of the following sort
$$
\int \frac{ax+b}{x^2+px+q}\,dx
$$
with $D=\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^2-q<0$ can be solved with the ansatz
$$
F(x) =
c_1\,\arctan\left(\frac{x+\frac{p}{2}}{\sqrt{-D}}\right)
+c_2\, \ln\left(x^2+px+q \right)
+c_3
$$
You get
$$
F'(x) =
\frac{c_1\sqrt{-D}}{x^2+px+q}
+\frac{c_2(2x+p)}{x^2+px+q}
=
\frac{c_1\sqrt{-D}+c_2(2x+p)}{x^2+px+q}
$$
(as an easy exercise for the reader).
Now, you only have to choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $2\,c_2 = a$ and $p\,c_2+\sqrt{-D}\;c_1 = b$

Might be an irrelevant question, but why is $D = (p/2)^2 - q$ instead of the traditional $p^2 - 4q$?

@BarackBarackBarack $a=1$ so the 2 in the denominator of the quadratic equation gets distributed. Hence the factor of $1/4$ because $D$ is inside a square root.
